# Parametros en consulta con firestore angular

Tags: sql

Quisiera poder llamar solo ciertos campos de un documento almacenado en firestore, con el fin de disminuir la cantidad de información del llamado, sin embargo solo logro traer el documento completo.
El llamado lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
return this.afs.collection('semaforos', ref => ref.orderBy('codid')).valueChanges();
```